# About packaging tiny bits of software

Tags: python, package

My main goal is to provide a Python software package that can be easily installed and upgraded by system administrators and easily maintained by the developer. The former is more important than the latter.

The package itself is large but depends on many really small utilities; many of them are just 20, 30 or 40 lines of code. Each utility might be useful without the main package.

Lacking any experience in this field, I'd like to ask if the correct way is to release the software as one main package and 10 tiny packages as its dependencies?

1. I have doubts if it makes sense to create a package where the `setup.py` is larger than the real code.
2. `pip` still does not have an `--upgrade-all` option

Wouldn't it be better simply to copy all the utilities into the main package and provide a single package only?

Comment: You could potentially just have .py files as a library and have a small script inside say a cx_Freeze executable which compares current library files with those hosted on an update server using urlopen?

Comment: If you own the code of all the packages, I would recommend to solve this via the build process. During development, have it set up to build packages for everything to help with sharing the utility code. When you release, include the utility code directly into the main package. That way, both user and developer have an easy life and only DevOps suffer. As usual.

Comment: @Elxafil Yes, I was thinking about a script to automate the task. I just need some help to make the decision.

Comment: @VPfB what I do is I create a library folder called "lib" inside my program directory that has cx_Freeze package it with it so then once the program is freezed you can then load them from the software directory same as normal, from there inside the main program/package you can have a little update script that checks for updates using either socket servers or urllib.